# Error in installing Flask using pip command in windows

Tags: python, pip

I tried to install Flask as well as *virtualenv* using pip command in windows command prompt but below error is showing. How can I fix this?

```
C:\Users\anupa>pip install Flask
Collecting Flask
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x06620E50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))': /simple/flask/

  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x06620DF0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))': /simple/flask/

  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x06620C30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))': /simple/flask/

  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x06620E10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))': /simple/flask/

  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x06620C90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))': /simple/flask/

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Flask
```

Comment: you obviously have an internet connection, but i get the exact same error when trying to install  it without a connection, so this seems very strange.

Comment: one of possible reasons pip can't install an HTTPS connection is a wrong system time. In this case, site certificate might be considered expired or not yet started. I would suggest to [download flask manually](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Perm/) and see if there is any error

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `pip` command,

```
$ pip install --proxy your_proxy_path Flask
```